# Does this method of proof work?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose I want to prove $a\neq b$.

I write $a=b$, simplify the expressions and eventually arrive at something like $1=2$ which is always false. Does this mean that the assumption $a=b$ is false?

Comment: Absolutely.  That's called *proof by contradiction*.

Comment: Beware that extraneous roots don't get you there.

Comment: @ncmathsadist what do you mean by extraneous roots? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @saulspatz I though this was different because I didn't contradict the assuption $a=b$, instead I arrived at something which is always false like $1=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your proof of $1=2$ is in fact the result of  the assumption  $a=b$,  not other assumptions, then you have used proof by contradiction and you have proved $ a\ne b.$

For example if I want to prove that $3\ne 4$ and argue that;

Let $3=4.$

Since $\sqrt 1 = -1,$  then $2=1+ \sqrt 1 =  1-1 =0$ which is false.

I have not proved $3\ne 4$ even if $2=0$ is always false.